# PC restarts randomly while applications are running

Tags: windows-10

I have several PC that restart randomly and from the EventViewer I found this error that both PC have:

*"The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Launch permission for the COM Server application
with CLSID Windows.SecurityCenter.WscBrokerManager and APPID Unavailable to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18)
from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable).
This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool."*

Anyone had this issue? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Run a complete set of hardware diagnostics for your particular computer. Update BIOS and all drivers with your driver update app.  Run DISM and SFC , restart and test.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW

Comment: That event might *not* be the cause  of the issue -- see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/event-10016-logged-when-accessing-dcom. However, search on the GUID, as shown in https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/109079-event-id-10016-distributedcom-windows-securitycenter-wscbrokermanager.html and fix it per https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/event-id-10016-distributedcom-windows-securitycenter-wscbrokermanager.28366/